# Public port 80 targeting private port 3000 on Azure Linux

Tags: virtualhost, reverse-proxy, azure, ubuntu-14.04

I have a Ruby on Rails website on Azure Linux (Ubuntu 14.04) that works perfectly from this address:

```
http://mydomain.cloudapp.net:3000
```

I want to get rid of the port in the address, and redirect it to a subdomain I have. I have set up the `000-default.conf` on Apache as per below:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myweb.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mywebsite
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
</VirtualHost>
```

I have restarted apache2. On my domain manager I have created a CNAME from `myweb.example.com` to `mydomain.cloudapp.net`.

However, when I enter `http://myweb.example.com` I get 500 internal server error. It does work with `http://myweb.example.com:3000`. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** error_log info after trying to access http://myweb.example.com

```
[Sun Aug 23 16:02:40.634116 2015] [proxy:warn] [pid 3189:tid 140710588688128] [c
lient 92.251.128.56:52583] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL /.
 If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are
 included in the configuration using LoadModule.
```

Comment: What do your logs say?

Comment: @EEAA question updated with log dump

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you just need to load `mod_proxy_http`.

Comment: That's it. sudo a2enmod proxy_http fixed my issue